# Styling border around div

Tags: html, css

I'm a bit stuck on styling border around div box.

The problem is that I can't make borders not to be like:

[image: demo]

Here is the real example what I have:

[image: Demo]

```css
.num.num_1 {
  border-left-color: #0D2431;
}
.num {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border-width: 5px;
  font-size: 40px;
}
.num {
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #0D2431;
  background-color: #fff;
}
div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="num num_1">1</div>
```

Comment: You will have to add a div to this and try to use perspective (`transform: skew`, maybe) to solve this problem, as borders are hard angled no matter how you slice it.

Comment: That's how borders work, they are slanted, that's what allows you to use them to make triangles using CSS. I would use the before pseudo-element to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Can you share the link to the website whose screenshot you've shared?

Comment: @FahadHasan what for?

Comment: It's CSS can be inspected for that part to find out how they're implementing that sort of a border.

Comment: @FahadHasan I have it locally and I the question already have been  answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.num.cheat:before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    left: -5px;
    right: -5px;
    top: -5px;
    bottom: -5px;
    
}
.num_1:before {
    border-left: 5px solid black;
}
.num_2:before {
    border-left: 5px solid black;
    border-top: 5px solid black;
}
.num_3:before {
    border-left: 5px solid black;
    border-top: 5px solid black;
    border-right: 5px solid black;
}
.num_4:before {
    border-left: 5px solid black;
    border-top: 5px solid black;
    border-right: 5px solid black;
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}
.num {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border-width: 5px;
  font-size: 40px;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.num {
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 5px solid #eee;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #0D2431;
  background-color: #fff;
}
div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="num num_1 cheat">1</div>
<div class="num num_2 cheat">2</div>
<div class="num num_3 cheat">3</div>
<div class="num num_4 cheat">4</div>
```

I modified your css a little bit. I solved it using the :before pseudo element.

Comment: Brilliant! But I have small question. It's a border for number 1, I have 4 number in totals, how I can make for number 2 `border-left` and `border-top`, for number 3 `border-left`, `border-top` and `border-right` and finally for number 4 `border-left`, `border-top`, `border-right` and `border-bottom`

Comment: I edited the fiddle to make it work in all four cases

Answer (score 1):

Better yet, you can use box-shadow to achieve this without any extra elements.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/w3b1uh7g/2/

```
.num {
  border-left: 0px;
  box-shadow: -5px 0 0 0 #0D2431;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a weird series of nested divs:

```css
.border {
    background: green;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
.border-left {
    padding-left: 10px;
    background: black;
    display: inline-block;
}
.inside-box {
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="border-left">
    <div class="border">
        <div class="inside-box">1</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add these to your css. the Pseudo Elements should make it square without adding extra divs in the HTML

```
.num.num_1:before {
content: "";
position: relative;
display: block;
top: -5px;
left: -5px;
height: 5px;
width: 5px;
background: black;
}

.num.num_1:after {
content: "";
position: relative;
display: block;
bottom: 0px;
left: -5px;
height: 5px;
width: 5px;
background: black;
}
```